# How to get Heroku running again now that free service has ended?

Tags: heroku, deployment, payment

I am a newer developer who has a few sites deployed on Heroku. Now that their free service is suspended, I am looking to pay for their cheapest services to get the sites running again. Unfortunately, Heroku has seemed to make this overly complicated and confusing, and I cannot figure out what services I need to subscribe to through them, and more frustratingly, where to even find the services I need to subscribe to and pay for. My deployed sites all use NodeJS and either a MySQL or MongoDB database. All have worked perfectly until now. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

I tried reading the Heroku documentation and Reddit to find how to get my sites working again. I was expecting to be able to easily log into Heroku and pay for my sites to continue running, but apparently it is a little more involved than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku did make it confusing for the new subscriptions. However, you can inspect the error message on your profile page and follow the instructions to subscribe to the lowest Eco plan. You will not have to pay at the moment, instead they will charge you after the billing cycle is over.

If you have previously deployed apps, you can still access them after the subscription. If you are still experiencing an **H14 error**, try to **reconfigure your dyno**. Just change your dyno type to the subscribed plan and make sure you have toggle the selected dyno to the right in order to enable it.

[image]

Comment: AH HA! Holy smokes that was so simple, I really appreciate the help! Can't believe I spent so long trying to figure out that I just needed to turn that slider to the 'on' position.